# Найдите в предложениях лексические ошибки, исправьте их

Tags: лексика

1.В заключение слово для доклада представили директору заводу. 2. В конце 80-х годов в партии и в стране сложилась достаточно сложная ситуация. 3. В честь старейших ветеранов нашего завода установлен памятный знак на проходной. 4. В преддверии предстоящего боя солдаты проверяли амуницию, чистили оружие. 5. В издательстве готовится к печати новая книга – автобиография жизни великого актера.

Где здесь ошибки? Я кроме орфографических не нашел ни одной лексической ошибки.

Comment: Хотя вроде нашел. 2. В конце 80-х годов в партии и в стране *сложилась* достаточно *сложная* ситуация. 
Здесь тавтология.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.предоставили  - смешение паронимов (представили-предоставили)2.-тавтология.3.- плеоназм.4-лексическая несочетаемость.5- плеоназм.

Исправленное:1.В заключение слово для доклада предОставили директору заводу. 2. В конце 80-х годов в партии и в стране сложилась достаточно трудная ситуация. 3. В честь старейших работников нашего завода установлен памятный знак на проходной. 4. Перед предстоящим боем солдаты проверяли амуницию, чистили оружие. 5. В издательстве готовится к печати новая книга – автобиография  великого актера.

Comment: Перед предстоящим - такая же избыточность, как и в преддверии предстоящего... Согласна с Виктором - просто в преддверии боя или перед боем.

Comment: Ларf, здесь именно лексическая несочетаемость, только я имела в виду не значение слова "преддверие", а его стилистическую функцию - преддверие - торжественное, для праздника,а бой - стилистически нейтральное, чуть сниженное(в отличие от битвы, например).Можно сказать, что это стилистическая ошибка.Хотя согласна, что и предстоящий - лишнее.

Answer (score 3):

Соглашаясь с предыдущими вариантами исправления,  вношу корективы: 2. В конце 80-х годов в партии и в стране возникла достаточно сложная ситуация (все-таки ситуация не складывается, а возникает). 3. В честь старейших работников нашего завода установлен памятный знак у проходной (предлог "у" здесь более уместен, так как установленный на проходной памятный знак будет мешать проходящим через проходную) . 4. В преддверии боя солдаты проверяли амуницию, чистили оружие.

Comment: Виктор,это праздник входит в дверь, а по отношению к бою это неприемлемо, лексическая ошибка - несочетаемость.А памятный знак - табличка, она именно вешается на дверь проходной, а не рядом с ней. Ситуация(совокупность обстоятельств, положение, обстановка)вполне может сложиться постепенно, а не возникнуть мгновенно.

Comment: Уважаемая Людмила! С.И. Ожегов дает следующее толкование слова "преддверие": "Начальный период чего-нибудь, время, непосредственно предшествующее чему-нибудь. В преддверии событий". Вывод делайте сама. Насчет памятного знака тоже не согласен с Вами. На двери такие предметы никогда не крепятся - только на стене рядом.

Answer (score 0):

~1. - предоставили (пусть будет смешение паронимов, хотя, вернее всего, это просто оговорка/описка. 
~2. - "достаточно" - слово-паразит, оно ничего не значит. Сложилась сложная - никак не плеоназм, разный смысл.
~3. - ошибки не вижу. Ветераны могут быть и не старейшие, а старейшие работники могут оказаться и не ветеранами *этого завода*.
~4. - ошибки не вижу. "Преддверие предстоящего" - стилистическая шероховатость, на ошибку не тянет. Тут смысл в том, что "преддверие" не стоит употреблять во временнОм значении, это категория пространственная. А в переносном (т.е временнОм значении) значении употребление - принадлежность высого стиля, очень, причем, пафосного. Или иронического. У боя нет преддверия, ни у предстоящего, ни у какого еще. Не плеоназм точно. Имхо. 
~5. - тут согласен. "автобиография жизни" - избыточность, "жизнь" лишняя, биография и так жизнеописание.